# SQL Server : convert table into a distinct binary version of itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to take a column, get the distinct values, create a new column for each distinct value and put a 1 in that col if the row had that value and 0 otherwise. See example. Any idea how to code this in a generic way that can handle any table without explicit cases done by hand for each distinct value in the column?

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (col1 varchar(5), col2 int)

insert into @YourTable values ('abcdf', 123)
insert into @YourTable values ('aaaaa', 456)
insert into @YourTable values ('bbbbb', 789)
insert into @YourTable values ('ccccc', 789)
insert into @YourTable values ('aaaaa', 789)
insert into @YourTable values ('abcdf', 789)

--This is source table
SELECT * FROM @YourTable

--Need this as result table
SELECT
    CASE WHEN col1 = 'abcdf' then 1 else 0 end as is_abcdf,
    CASE WHEN col1 = 'aaaaa' then 1 else 0 end as is_aaaaa,
    CASE WHEN col1 = 'bbbbb' then 1 else 0 end as is_bbbbb,
    CASE WHEN col1 = 'ccccc' then 1 else 0 end as is_ccccc,
    CASE WHEN col2 = 123 then 1 else 0 end as is_123,
    CASE WHEN col2 = 456 then 1 else 0 end as is_456,
    CASE WHEN col2 = 789 then 1 else 0 end as is_789
FROM 
    @YourTable
```

Comment: you'll need a dynamic pivot

Comment: Your result does not make lot of sense..

Comment: thanks Lamar; I will look into that method!